# Get users countrycode (ISO 3166-1) in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, nslocale

I see that the `NSLocale` bindings aren't complete in MonoTouch so I am having a bit difficulties writing them myself.

Does anyone have the code to get the users countrycode in ISO 3166-1 alpha 3 format? Three letters for each country: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3

This is being ported from Android where we already have the API call:

```
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Country();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Iphone, Obtaining a List of countries from MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577535/iphone-obtaining-a-list-of-countries-from-monotouch) - it should cover it (or easily be adapted to do so).

note: this will be part of a future version of MonoTouch (got the code in a backup waiting for my iMac reparation ;-)

**EDIT**

iOS `NSLocale` returns the ISO **2** letters country code [not the ISO **3** letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447242/always-get-iso-639-2-three-character-language-code-in-ios) you're looking for. The best you can do is build a map from 2->3 letters and use the linked code to get the 2 letters code. There's some code to do the reverse (that you can adapt) or even a map (to reverse) available in: [Converting country codes in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884692/converting-country-codes-in-net)

Note that depending on your requirements this could be incomplete and not exactly matching what Android provides you.

Comment: I guess my opinion of easy isn't the same as yours :-) I had a look at that question before posting mine and tried to adapt it with little success. Can you push me a little more in the right direction? Guess I should read up on the bindings part of MonoTouch...

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll just map them manually since I only need 20-30 countries supported.