# Three letter country code on iOS

Tags: ios, country-codes

I know you are able to get the two letter country code on iOS, for all countries.
But is there a way to get the three letter country code?

So from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am talking about the country code http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3, not the language code.

Comment: Incorrectly marked as duplicate.

Comment: Totally incorrectly marked as duplicate.

Comment: this question is incorrectly marked as duplicate

Comment: Incorrecly marked as duplicate. I haven't found an answer on this so far. @Cosmin have you found a solution?

Comment: I ended up doing my own conversion as I don't believe it comes with the iOS framework. If anyone needs it in the future I posted my answer here in one of the duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447242/always-get-iso-639-2-three-character-language-code-in-ios/42457326#42457326