# Convert country code 2 letter to 3 letter in Objective-C

Tags: android, ios, objective-c

I'm working on a function that gets the country code from the phone, but when I get the country code it consists of 2 letters, but I want it to return three letters.

For example `US -> USA`

In Android, java supports converting from 2 characters to 3 characters with the following code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", countryCode);
return locale.getISO3Country();
```

But in iOS with Objective-C I don't know how to convert it, so can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434248/three-letter-country-code-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of standardisation there is no ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 code on apple platforms to convert to. More the other way around, you could use a 3 letter code and still find the 2 letter code.

and if you want to keep at least some consistency to your android code then you need to implement some LUT table supporting this off-standard feature yourself.  The available list is not very long anyway (256 codes).

```objectivec
NSArray *isoCountrys = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];
for (NSString *code in isoCountrys) {
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:code];
     // country name in native language
    NSString *country = [locale localizedStringForCountryCode:code];
    NSString *iso3 = LUTisoA3counterpartCodes[code];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@",code, iso3, country, locale.localeIdentifier);
}
```

Docu `NSLocale` [-localizedStringForCountryCode:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1642920-localizedstringforcountrycode?language=objc)

Docu `NSLocale` [-countryCode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1643060-countrycode?language=objc)

the LUT could look like.. and is much better stored in a plist then the following runtime allocated dictionary.

```objectivec
NSDictionary *LUTisoA3counterpartCodes = @{
    @"AC":@"SHN",@"AW":@"ABW",@"AF":@"AFG",@"AO":@"AGO",@"AI":@"AIA",@"AX":@"ALA",
    @"AL":@"ALB",@"AD":@"AND",@"AE":@"ARE",@"AR":@"ARG",@"AM":@"ARM",@"AS":@"ASM",
    @"AQ":@"ATA",@"TF":@"ATF",@"AG":@"ATG",@"AU":@"AUS",@"AT":@"AUT",@"AZ":@"AZE",
    @"BI":@"BDI",@"BE":@"BEL",@"BJ":@"BEN",@"BQ":@"BES",@"BF":@"BFA",@"BD":@"BGD",
    @"BG":@"BGR",@"BH":@"BHR",@"BS":@"BHS",@"BA":@"BIH",@"BL":@"BLM",@"BY":@"BLR",
    @"BZ":@"BLZ",@"BM":@"BMU",@"BO":@"BOL",@"BR":@"BRA",@"BB":@"BRB",@"BN":@"BRN",
    @"BT":@"BTN",@"BV":@"BVT",@"BW":@"BWA",@"CF":@"CAF",@"CA":@"CAN",@"CC":@"CCK",
    @"CH":@"CHE",@"CL":@"CHL",@"CN":@"CHN",@"CI":@"CIV",@"CM":@"CMR",@"CD":@"COD",
    @"CG":@"COG",@"CK":@"COK",@"CO":@"COL",@"KM":@"COM",@"CV":@"CPV",@"CR":@"CRI",
    @"CU":@"CUB",@"CW":@"CUW",@"CX":@"CXR",@"KY":@"CYM",@"CY":@"CYP",@"CZ":@"CZE",
    @"DE":@"DEU",@"DJ":@"DJI",@"DM":@"DMA",@"DK":@"DNK",@"DO":@"DOM",@"DZ":@"DZA",
    @"EC":@"ECU",@"EG":@"EGY",@"ER":@"ERI",@"EH":@"ESH",@"ES":@"ESP",@"EE":@"EST",
    @"ET":@"ETH",@"FI":@"FIN",@"FJ":@"FJI",@"FK":@"FLK",@"FR":@"FRA",@"FO":@"FRO",
    @"FM":@"FSM",@"GA":@"GAB",@"GB":@"GBR",@"GE":@"GEO",@"GG":@"GGY",@"GH":@"GHA",
    @"GI":@"GIB",@"GN":@"GIN",@"GP":@"GLP",@"GM":@"GMB",@"GW":@"GNB",@"GQ":@"GNQ",
    @"GR":@"GRC",@"GD":@"GRD",@"GL":@"GRL",@"GT":@"GTM",@"GF":@"GUF",@"GU":@"GUM",
    @"GY":@"GUY",@"HK":@"HKG",@"HM":@"HMD",@"HN":@"HND",@"HR":@"HRV",@"HT":@"HTI",
    @"HU":@"HUN",@"ID":@"IDN",@"IM":@"IMN",@"IN":@"IND",@"IO":@"IOT",@"IE":@"IRL",
    @"IR":@"IRN",@"IQ":@"IRQ",@"IS":@"ISL",@"IL":@"ISR",@"IT":@"ITA",@"JM":@"JAM",
    @"JE":@"JEY",@"JO":@"JOR",@"JP":@"JPN",@"KZ":@"KAZ",@"KE":@"KEN",@"KG":@"KGZ",
    @"KH":@"KHM",@"KI":@"KIR",@"KN":@"KNA",@"KR":@"KOR",@"KW":@"KWT",@"LA":@"LAO",
    @"LB":@"LBN",@"LR":@"LBR",@"LY":@"LBY",@"LC":@"LCA",@"LI":@"LIE",@"LK":@"LKA",
    @"LS":@"LSO",@"LT":@"LTU",@"LU":@"LUX",@"LV":@"LVA",@"MO":@"MAC",@"MF":@"MAF",
    @"MA":@"MAR",@"MC":@"MCO",@"MD":@"MDA",@"MG":@"MDG",@"MV":@"MDV",@"MX":@"MEX",
    @"MH":@"MHL",@"MK":@"MKD",@"ML":@"MLI",@"MT":@"MLT",@"MM":@"MMR",@"ME":@"MNE",
    @"MN":@"MNG",@"MP":@"MNP",@"MZ":@"MOZ",@"MR":@"MRT",@"MS":@"MSR",@"MQ":@"MTQ",
    @"MU":@"MUS",@"MW":@"MWI",@"MY":@"MYS",@"YT":@"MYT",@"NA":@"NAM",@"NC":@"NCL",
    @"NE":@"NER",@"NF":@"NFK",@"NG":@"NGA",@"NI":@"NIC",@"NU":@"NIU",@"NL":@"NLD",
    @"NO":@"NOR",@"NP":@"NPL",@"NR":@"NRU",@"NZ":@"NZL",@"OM":@"OMN",@"PK":@"PAK",
    @"PA":@"PAN",@"PN":@"PCN",@"PE":@"PER",@"PH":@"PHL",@"PW":@"PLW",@"PG":@"PNG",
    @"PL":@"POL",@"PR":@"PRI",@"KP":@"PRK",@"PT":@"PRT",@"PY":@"PRY",@"PS":@"PSE",
    @"PF":@"PYF",@"QA":@"QAT",@"RE":@"REU",@"RO":@"ROU",@"RU":@"RUS",@"RW":@"RWA",
    @"SA":@"SAU",@"SD":@"SDN",@"SN":@"SEN",@"SG":@"SGP",@"GS":@"SGS",@"SH":@"SHN",
    @"SJ":@"SJM",@"SB":@"SLB",@"SL":@"SLE",@"SV":@"SLV",@"SM":@"SMR",@"SO":@"SOM",
    @"PM":@"SPM",@"RS":@"SRB",@"SS":@"SSD",@"ST":@"STP",@"SR":@"SUR",@"SK":@"SVK",
    @"SI":@"SVN",@"SE":@"SWE",@"SZ":@"SWZ",@"SX":@"SXM",@"SC":@"SYC",@"SY":@"SYR",
    @"TC":@"TCA",@"TD":@"TCD",@"TG":@"TGO",@"TH":@"THA",@"TJ":@"TJK",@"TK":@"TKL",
    @"TM":@"TKM",@"TL":@"TLS",@"TO":@"TON",@"TT":@"TTO",@"TN":@"TUN",@"TR":@"TUR",
    @"TV":@"TUV",@"TW":@"TWN",@"TZ":@"TZA",@"UG":@"UGA",@"UA":@"UKR",@"UM":@"UMI",
    @"UY":@"URY",@"US":@"USA",@"UZ":@"UZB",@"VA":@"VAT",@"VC":@"VCT",@"VE":@"VEN",
    @"VG":@"VGB",@"VI":@"VIR",@"VN":@"VNM",@"VU":@"VUT",@"WF":@"WLF",@"WS":@"WSM",
    @"XK":@"XKV",@"YE":@"YEM",@"ZA":@"ZAF",@"ZM":@"ZMB",@"ZW":@"ZWE",
    //unknown status or codes, to be changed soon
    @"DG":@"DGA" , //Diego Garcia
    @"EA":@"EA_" , //Ceuta and Melilla
    @"CP":@"CPT" , //Clipperton Island -> French Polynesia
    @"IC":@"IC_" , //Kanarian Island
    @"TA":@"TAA" , //டிரிஸ்டன் டா குன்ஹா , Tristan da Cunha -> St.Helena
};
```

this LUT makes it easy to lookup by 2 letter code and get the 3 letter codes. And in reality the list is much longer and matter of permanent changes.

and if you trust the sorting of Apples API you could just use a static NSArray instead of a plist or NSDictionary. The following prints it for use..

```objectivec
int i=1;
fprintf(stderr,"\nstatic NSString *isoA3accordingToAppleSorting[256] = {\n");
for (NSString *code in isoCountrys) {
    if (i%20 == 19) fprintf(stderr,"\n");
    NSString *iso3 = LUTisoA3counterpartCodes[code];
    fprintf(stderr,"@\"%s\",",iso3.UTF8String);
    i++;
}
fprintf(stderr,"};\n");
```

which looks like..

```
static NSString *countryCodeAsA3accordingToAppleSorting[256] = {
@"SHN",@"AND",@"ARE",@"AFG",@"ATG",@"AIA",@"ALB",@"ARM",@"AGO",@"ATA",@"ARG",@"ASM",@"AUT",@"AUS",@"ABW",@"ALA",@"AZE",@"BIH",
@"BRB",@"BGD",@"BEL",@"BFA",@"BGR",@"BHR",@"BDI",@"BEN",@"BLM",@"BMU",@"BRN",@"BOL",@"BES",@"BRA",@"BHS",@"BTN",@"BVT",@"BWA",@"BLR",@"BLZ",
@"CAN",@"CCK",@"COD",@"CAF",@"COG",@"CHE",@"CIV",@"COK",@"CHL",@"CMR",@"CHN",@"COL",@"CPT",@"CRI",@"CUB",@"CPV",@"CUW",@"CXR",@"CYP",@"CZE",
@"DEU",@"DGA",@"DJI",@"DNK",@"DMA",@"DOM",@"DZA",@"EA_",@"ECU",@"EST",@"EGY",@"ESH",@"ERI",@"ESP",@"ETH",@"FIN",@"FJI",@"FLK",@"FSM",@"FRO",
@"FRA",@"GAB",@"GBR",@"GRD",@"GEO",@"GUF",@"GGY",@"GHA",@"GIB",@"GRL",@"GMB",@"GIN",@"GLP",@"GNQ",@"GRC",@"SGS",@"GTM",@"GUM",@"GNB",@"GUY",
@"HKG",@"HMD",@"HND",@"HRV",@"HTI",@"HUN",@"IC_",@"IDN",@"IRL",@"ISR",@"IMN",@"IND",@"IOT",@"IRQ",@"IRN",@"ISL",@"ITA",@"JEY",@"JAM",@"JOR",
@"JPN",@"KEN",@"KGZ",@"KHM",@"KIR",@"COM",@"KNA",@"PRK",@"KOR",@"KWT",@"CYM",@"KAZ",@"LAO",@"LBN",@"LCA",@"LIE",@"LKA",@"LBR",@"LSO",@"LTU",
@"LUX",@"LVA",@"LBY",@"MAR",@"MCO",@"MDA",@"MNE",@"MAF",@"MDG",@"MHL",@"MKD",@"MLI",@"MMR",@"MNG",@"MAC",@"MNP",@"MTQ",@"MRT",@"MSR",@"MLT",
@"MUS",@"MDV",@"MWI",@"MEX",@"MYS",@"MOZ",@"NAM",@"NCL",@"NER",@"NFK",@"NGA",@"NIC",@"NLD",@"NOR",@"NPL",@"NRU",@"NIU",@"NZL",@"OMN",@"PAN",
@"PER",@"PYF",@"PNG",@"PHL",@"PAK",@"POL",@"SPM",@"PCN",@"PRI",@"PSE",@"PRT",@"PLW",@"PRY",@"QAT",@"REU",@"ROU",@"SRB",@"RUS",@"RWA",@"SAU",
@"SLB",@"SYC",@"SDN",@"SWE",@"SGP",@"SHN",@"SVN",@"SJM",@"SVK",@"SLE",@"SMR",@"SEN",@"SOM",@"SUR",@"SSD",@"STP",@"SLV",@"SXM",@"SYR",@"SWZ",
@"TAA",@"TCA",@"TCD",@"ATF",@"TGO",@"THA",@"TJK",@"TKL",@"TLS",@"TKM",@"TUN",@"TON",@"TUR",@"TTO",@"TUV",@"TWN",@"TZA",@"UKR",@"UGA",@"UMI",
@"USA",@"URY",@"UZB",@"VAT",@"VCT",@"VEN",@"VGB",@"VIR",@"VNM",@"VUT",@"WLF",@"WSM",@"XKV",@"YEM",@"MYT",@"ZAF",@"ZMB",@"ZWE",};
```

but then you have to find the index of your 2 letter code in apples ISOCountryCodes to look them up accordingly.

Reminder. The ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 explains only that it should have 3 letters, not which letter exactly

Comment: 2 BG there. "BG": "BGR" and  "BG": "BLR". Should be  "BY": "BLR"

Comment: thanks for the hint, almost tend to mark it RU. The list is matter of permanent changes and as written there is no standard for the code itself, just a standard(iso) declaring what a two or three letter country code is, not which one it should be. In case of Belarus, we could even test and send it to Russias Minsk and it would reach the mailbox for sure for obvious reasons.